# Prove that $\Bbb{Z}×\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Z}×\Bbb{Z}×\Bbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Considering them as rings, I can prove that they are not isomorphic as they have different nos of idempotent elements , but in case of group isomorphism I am unable to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: consider the possible cardinalities of sets of odd elements such that the sum of any two is odd. Alternatively, show that if $G_1$, $G_2$ are isomorphic abelian groups, then $G_1/2G_1$ and $G_2/2G_2$ are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ can be generated by $2$ elements.

$\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ cannot be generated by $2$ elements.

(Prove that for two elements $(a,b,c)$ and $(u,v,w)$ the set $\{n(a,b,c)+m(u,v,w)\mid n,m\in\mathbb Z\}$ is Always a **proper** subset of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$)

Comment: Of course the second line requires proof.

Answer (score 1):

That results from the *Invariant Basis Number* property in commutative rings: they're frr $\bf Z$-modules, with a basis of $2$ and $3$ vectors respectively.