# Proof Verification: If $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal, then $(R/I)^n\cong (R/I)^m$ as $R$-modules iff $n=m$

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra

My argument is as follows:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, $I$ an ideal of $R$.
If $(R/I)^n\cong (R/I)^m$ as $R$-modules, then it follows that they are isomorphic as $R/I$-modules because the isomorphism factors through the quotient. We observe that these are both free $R/I$-modules with bases $${\mathfrak{B}_1=\{\delta_{1j}+I, \delta_{2j}+I, \dots, \delta_{nj}+I\} \;\;\text{ and }\;\; \mathfrak{B}_2=\{\delta_{1j}+I, \delta_{2j}+I, \dots, \delta_{mj}+I\}}$$ respectively.
Then the isomorphism between $(R/I)^n \cong (R/I)^m$ as $R$-modules induces an isomorphism of these free modules, meaning there is a bijection between the elements of $\mathfrak{B}_1$ and $\mathfrak{B}_2$. It follows then that $n=m$.

Comment: What's $J{{}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, you've essentially showed the following:

> Let $R \rightarrow S$ be an epimorphism of rings.  Then $S^m \cong S^n$ as $R$-modules iff $m = n$.

Indeed, the $R$-module isomorphism extends to an $S$-module isomorphism $S^m \otimes_R S\cong S^n \otimes_R S$.  Since tensor products commute with direct sums, you get an isomorphism $(S \otimes_R S)^m \cong (S \otimes_R S)^n$.  Since $R \rightarrow S$ is an epimorphism, the multiplication map $S \otimes_R S \rightarrow S$ is an isomorphism.  Finally conclude $m = n$ because commutative rings have IBN (do make sure that you understand that part of the argument.  As Captain Lama noted, your reasoning there was faulty).

This naturally raises the question

> Can it happen that $S^m \cong S^n$ and $m \not= n$ when $R \rightarrow S$ is not an epimorphism?

Yes, it can. Consider for example any ring $R$ and the ring $S = R^\mathbb{N}$ (product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{N}$).

We have an $R$-module isomorphism $S^2 \cong S$ given by $\big((r_1, r_2, \ldots), (q_1, q_2, \ldots) \big) \leadsto (r_1, q_1, r_2, q_2, \ldots)$.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there are two different points at stake here.

1. If $M$ and $N$ are two $R/I$-modules, then they are isomorphic iff they are isomorphic as $R$-modules. I think you explained that correctly.
2. If $A$ is any commutative ring (here $A=R/I$) then $A^n\simeq A^m$ as $A$-modules iff $n=m$. This is a more delicate result, and I am not sure you understood it properly. The way you wrote your proof seems to assume that an isomorphism will necessarily induce a bijection between the bases you chose, which is clearly not true. One way to show this is to take any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$, and take the quotient, which gives an isomorphism $(A/\mathfrak{m})^n\simeq (A/\mathfrak{m})^m$, and since those are vector spaces over $A/\mathfrak{m}$, we can use basic linear algebra to conclude that $n=m$. (See also [$R^n \cong R^m$ iff $n=m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142128/rn-cong-rm-iff-n-m))