# Proof that if $R$ is a commutative ring and $R^n \cong R^m$ then $n=m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modules

**Problem:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring, show that if $R^n \cong R^m$ then $n = m$.

I have an attempt which I think is alright, but I just want to double check that there are no issues in my attempt. It's a very basic from the definitions approach, and didn't see anything exactly like it on the site. I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428171/r-is-a-commutative-ring-with-1-ne-0-and-rm-cong-rn-then-m-n?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I haven't studied tensor products yet.

> Attempt:We use exercise 10.2.12 from DF, if $R$ is a ring and $I$ is a left ideal of $R$, then $R^n/IR^n \cong \underbrace{R/IR \times \dots \times R/IR}_{n \text{ times}}$. Let $I$ be a maximal ideal of $R$, note that because $R$ is commutative, $I$ is a $2$-sided ideal. Because $R^n \cong R^m$ there is an $R$-module isomorphism $\varphi:R^n \rightarrow R^m$ which induces an isomorphism $\psi: R^n/IR^n \rightarrow R^m/IR^m$ defined by $r+IR^n \mapsto \varphi(r)+IR^m$. To see that this map is well-defined, let $r,r'$ be representatives of the same equivalence class, i.e $r+IR^n = r'+IR^n$. Then it follows that $r-r' \in IR^n$ so $r-r' = \sum_1^k a_im_i$ where $a_i \in I$ and $m_i \in R^n$. Then notice
> \begin{align*}
>   \psi(r)-\psi(r') &= \varphi(r)+IR^m - \varphi(r')+IR^m \\
>   & = \varphi(r-r')+IR^m \\
>   & = \varphi \left( \sum_1^k a_i m_i \right) + IR^m \\
>   & = \sum_1^k a_i\varphi(m_i) + IR^m \\
>   &= IR^m \tag{$\varphi(m_i) \in R^m$ and $a_i \in I$}
>  \end{align*}
> so $\psi(r)+IR^m = \psi(r')+IR^m$ and the map is well-defined. It follows from the fact that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism that $\psi$ is also an isomorphism. Therefore we can apply 10.2.12 from Dummit and Foote. We have that $R^n/IR^n \cong R^m/IR^m$ and so by 10.2.12 we have that
> $$
> \underbrace{R/IR \times \dots \times R/IR}_{n \text{ times }} \cong \underbrace{R/IR \times \dots \times R/IR}_{m \text{ times}}
> $$
> Since $R$ is commutative $I$ is two sided and it follows that $IR = I$; it's obvious that $I \subseteq IR$, if $\sum_1^ka_ir_i \in IR$ since $I$ is a two sided ideal $a_ir_i \in I$ for all $i$ so is an element of the ideal. Therefore This becomes
> $$
> \underbrace{R/I \times \dots \times R/I}_{n \text{ times }} \cong \underbrace{R/I \times \dots \times R/I}_{m \text{ times}}.
> $$
> Because $I$ was a maximal ideal we know that $R/I$ is a field and so this gives that $F^n \cong F^m$, but we know from vector space theory that these are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension, i.,e $n = m$.

Let me know if there are any missteps or places to trim the fat.

Comment: Yes, this is fine. You don't need to explicitly mention that $I$ is two-sided.

Comment: You've essentially provided details for same solution listed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1428964/29335), beginning with "If localization is not your thing..."